# Add White Background to plot.xts() Legend [R]

Tags: r, plot, xts

I am looking to plot several time series using plot.xts(), the built-in package for xts objects in R.

Currently, I am using the following:

```
## Create xts dataset
ust <- merge.xts(us.3m, 
                 us.6m,
                 us.2y,
                 us.3y,
                 us.5y,
                 us.10y,
                 us.30y)
## Create color scheme using rainbow()
tsRainbow = rainbow(ncol(as.zoo(ust)))

## Create plot of dataset
plot.xts(ust, screens=1,
             major.ticks="years",
             main="U.S. Bond Yield Evolution",
             yaxis.right=FALSE,
             grid.ticks.on="years",
             col=tsRainbow)
## Add legend
addLegend("topright", 
              legend.names=c("US 3M", "US 6M", 
                       "US 2Y", "US 3Y", 
                       "US 5Y", "US 10Y", "US 30Y"),
              col=tsRainbow,
              lty=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
              lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
              ncol=2,
              bg="white")
```

This produces the following graph:

[image: Evolution of Bond Yields]

**I would like to add a white overlay background to the legend**, so that the gridlines can not be seen in the legend area.  This will make the graph area much cleaner, and allow the legend labels to be seen in a publication-like document.

### Edit

The solution given by @JuliusVainora worked well.  Simple fix to my problem.

[image: Updated image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
addLegend("topright", 
          legend.names=c("US 3M", "US 6M", 
                         "US 2Y", "US 3Y", 
                         "US 5Y", "US 10Y", "US 30Y"),
          col=tsRainbow,
          lty=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
          lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
          ncol=2,
          bg="white",
          bty="o")
```

where `bty="o"` gives a complete box with a white background. If you wish the border color to be white as well, add `box.col="white"`.